# Creating an user without a password

Tags: linux, authentication, ubuntu

I'm trying to create user without password like this:

```
sudo adduser \
   --system \
   --shell /bin/bash \
   --gecos ‘User for managing of git version control’ \
   --group \
   --disabled-password \
   --home /home/git \
   git
```

It's created fine. But when I try to login under the git user I'm getting the password entering:

```
su git
Password:...
```

When I leave it empty I get an error:

```
su: Authentication failed
```

What's wrong?

Comment: shouldn't that go to [http://unix.stackexchange.com/](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I am not 100% sure (only about 90%) but doesn't `su` prompt for the *root-password*?

Answer (score 1):

"Disabled-password" doesn't disable authentication; it allows for non-password means of authenticating.  Your "su" command isn't using any of those, so it prompts for a password.  There won't be any that match the hashed string.

As a privileged user, you can delete the hashed password string and enable logins without any authentication (bad idea for this account).  Better is to either set up sudo or ssh to allow a specific list of users to assume this identity.